# SOATest value Assertion failed for data source lookup

Tags: json, testing, automated-tests, parasoft

I am using parasoft SOATest to test a service response and I got a failure 
`Message: DataSource: products (row 1): Value Assertion: For element "../item", expected: abc but was: bcd`

My Requirement is to validate the following response.

```
{
    "samples" : {
        "prds" : [
            "abc",
            "bcd"
        ]
    }
}
```

And I have a datasource table which is like follows. First row as the column name.

1. prds
2. abc
3. bcd

In the SOATest I have a JSON Assertor and inside JSON Assertor I have configured a Value Assertion. In the Value Assertion I selected the first item and then in the next step I selected `Apply to all "item[*]"`. Then Finish.

In the Expected Value I select Parameterized and select the `prds` from the drop down menu.

After all when the service return the above payload it failed with the above given message.

Is this a bug/limitation of SOATest or am I missing some step in here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just because you opted  **Apply to all "item[*]"** instead of  **Apply to "item[1]" Only**